# Finding a linear transformation from the dimension of the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The the question is: let $L_1 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map satisfying $\dim\mathrm{ker}(L_1)=3$, find $L_1$.

Ok so do I have to solve this by trial and error, or is there a specific way to find the transformation?

Comment: Compare the dimension of the kernel to the dimension of the domain. What does this tell you about the transformation’s image?

Comment: it is 0 bc of the rank-nullity theorem omg

Comment: I take it that ”omg” means that the light bulb came on :)

Comment: yes and a realization of how stupid I am lmao